# Uncaught TypeError Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, jquery-events

I am getting this error when my page loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
b.extend.globalEval
b.fn.extend.domManip
b.fn.extend.append
(anonymous function)
b.extend.access
b.fn.extend.html
(anonymous function)
c
p.fireWith
k
r
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

I thought it may have to do with a Jquery conflict, so I add `$.noConflict();` before the function call.  Still I am not sure how can we see if there is Jquery conflict present in our page or not.

Here is my code:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- 
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
-->

<link type="text/css" href="jquery.datepick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datepick.js"></script>

<?php
  echo "<script>User();</script>";
?>

<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script>

  $(function() {
    $( "#fast" ).datepicker();
  });

</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#modal').draggable({ handle: "p" });
  });
</script>
```

My major question is how we can see if conflicts exist or not and how to remove them.  What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: is there a reason why you are using relative paths?

Comment: Try removing some of the jQuery files and see if it works.

Comment: @lbu so that everything will be on my server,

Comment: @putvande point is which one ..

Comment: Well, you have to try, I can't help you since you have relative files which I don't have.

Comment: @putvande these path contain the same content as the http one

Comment: Well, than I would suggest removing `jquery.datepick.js` since jQuery ui has the datepicker in the sourcecode.

Comment: Is it possible when you downloaded the jquery ui library, that you accidentally excluded the datepicker widget?

Comment: in case you use `github.com/kbwood/datepick` the function to use is `$("#fast").datepick();`

Comment: @putvande i removed but still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are calling these scripts form a NON-SSL site ,I mean it should be HTTP your site name instead of HTTPS.otherwise it will get blocked

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue because of jQuery conflict and the following fixed it:

Replace

`$(function() {
    $( "#fast" ).datepicker();
  });`

by

`jQuery(function($) {
    $( "#fast" ).datepicker();
  });`